# Getting Not Logged In Error! for 200 Response

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, ui-automation, web-api-testing

I am trying with simple scenario stated below:

- Initiating the Webdriver instance and logging in to the facebook page
- trying to GET the response for the `Browser_all/nullState.php?**sometext`
  for the same

I am getting following error.

```
Error ! Not Logged in
```

though I am getting the 200 response, and as mentioned I am hitting the url after logging into my FB account can somebody help me and let me know why I am getting this error response and any suggestion to how to overcome it?

I have written the httpClient using `HttpURLConnection` api in java.

Comment: Are you saying that you are logging in to Facebook with your browser, but then you're trying to get to a URL in Facebook with `HttpURLConnection`?

Comment: I have written a code using java,selenium to open the FB and login post when I login I am trying to get the responSe information I.e code and header for which I used http client

Comment: Well, you have to use the same client for logging in and for making requests. Logging in sets a cookie in the client. If you use a different client, it doesn't use the cookie. It's like logging in to FB on Firefox and then wondering why you are not logged in in Chrome.